# Cant curl on Route53 record for Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I created an ELB on AWS for one of my database clusters. I also created a Route53 entry associated with the ELB. The Route53 record is a type A record with an alias to the ELB.

I can curl just fine when using the ELB endpoint but cannot resolve the host when using the Route53 entry.

Both - the ELB and the hosted zone are in the same VPC

Comment: Does the Route 53 DNS Name resolve to an IP address? Is it a Public or a Private IP address?

Comment: Is it public or private R53 hosted zone?

Comment: @marcin R53 is currently public, but I have tried private as well and neither works

Comment: @JohnRotenstein R53 DNS record resolves/points to the ELB A record of format xxxx.yyyy.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 1):

So here what I did to resolve the issue:

-My elb was public facing, i changed it to private
-created a new private hosted zone and an A type entry for the elb
-made sure that elb was associated with private subnets

and it worked